# angular bootstrap typeahead filter

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-typeahead

Here's a plunker showing the problem I'm seeing:

http://plnkr.co/edit/TKIHuNzPrrXlbzEdjdqN?p=preview

I want a typeahead where the user can only select from provided options.  I have the following HTML:

```
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<input type = "text" ng-model = "receiver.value" class = "give-recipient" 
 typeahead = "user for user in users" typeahead-editable = "false">
```

It displays a typeahead, but it does **not** filter on what I type. IOW, I expect that if I type a "g", only users with "g" in their names should show up, but all users show up, with matching letters bolded.

What are the settings I need to use?  Thank you,
Greg

Comment: If possible please provide fiddle or plunker

Comment: The `typeahead` directive - is this your own or are you using a library?

Comment: It's Angular Bootstrap.  That's the script link

Comment: I've added a Plunker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change

```
typeahead="user for user in users"
```

to

```
typeahead="user for user in users | filter:$viewValue "
```

The [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) documentation states that $viewValue is a

> variable that corresponds to the value entered inside the input

A working plunkr can be seen [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/InCygv0JLoyfQa7af8q7?p=preview)

Comment: Hi @dorzey, How can we pass on a comparator function for this case?

Comment: nevermind. it was easy and as given on angularjs org site. no changes.